# PortAudio: short noise at start and end of sound

Tags: c++, qt, audio, portaudio

I have piano-like application, and when I'm pressing piano key, it plays a sound. In my app I wrote my own sine wave generator. App is wrote in Qt. I think that problem is with portAudio, but I can't find any solution for this.

I've recorded for you how my problem sounds: https://vocaroo.com/i/s1yiWjaJffTU

And here is my generator class:

soundEngine.h

```
#ifndef SOUNDENGINE_H
#define SOUNDENGINE_H

#include <QThread>
#include <math.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

#define SAMPLE_RATE   (44100)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER  (64)
#define FREQUENCY 220

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI  (3.14159265)
#endif

#define TABLE_SIZE   (200)

typedef struct
{
    float sine[TABLE_SIZE];
    int phase;
}
paTestData;

class SoundEngine : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    bool turnOFF;
    void run();
    static int patestCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,unsigned long framesPerBuffer,const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,void *userData );
    void generateSine();
    void removeSine();
private:
    paTestData data;
    PaStream *stream;
    PaError err;
    bool isPressed;
};

#endif // SOUNDENGINE_H
```

soundEngine.cpp

```
#include "soundengine.h"
#include <QDebug>

void SoundEngine::run()
{
    PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
    int i;
    double t;
    turnOFF = false;
    isPressed = false;

    static unsigned long n=0;
    for( i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++, n++ )
    {
        t = (double)i/(double)SAMPLE_RATE;
        data.sine[i] = 0;
        //data.sine[i] = 0.3*sin(2 * M_PI * FREQUENCY * t);
        /*data.sine[i] *= 1.0/2;
        data.sine[i] += 0.5*sin(2 * M_PI * (FREQUENCY+110) * t);
        data.sine[i] *= 2.0/3;
        data.sine[i] += (1.0/3)*sin(2 * M_PI * (FREQUENCY+60) * t);
        data.sine[i] *= 3.0/4;
        data.sine[i] += (1.0/4)*sin(2 * M_PI * (FREQUENCY+160) * t);*/
    }
    data.phase = 0;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy inicjalizacji strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);

    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(); /* default output device */
    if (outputParameters.device == paNoDevice) qDebug()<<"Błąd: Brak domyślnego urządzenia wyjścia!";

    outputParameters.channelCount = 2;       /* stereo output */
    outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32; /* 32 bit floating point output */
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device )->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              NULL, /* no input */
              &outputParameters,
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /*paNoFlag we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              patestCallback,
              &data );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy otwieraniu strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);
    //err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy starcie strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);

    while (turnOFF == false) {
        Pa_Sleep(500);
    }

    //err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy zatrzymywaniu strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);
    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if(err != paNoError) qDebug()<<"Błąd przy zamykaniu strumienia:"<<Pa_GetErrorText(err);
    Pa_Terminate();
}

int SoundEngine::patestCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    paTestData *callData = (paTestData*)userData;
    float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    float sample;
    unsigned long i;

    (void) timeInfo; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) inputBuffer;

    for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
    {
        sample = callData->sine[callData->phase++];
        *out++ = sample;  /* left */
        *out++ = sample;  /* right */
        if( callData->phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) callData->phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
    }

    return paContinue;
}

void SoundEngine::generateSine()
{
    if(isPressed == false)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        {
            data.sine[i] += 0.3*sin(2 * M_PI * 440 * ((double)i/(double)SAMPLE_RATE));
        }
        isPressed = true;
        err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    }
}

void SoundEngine::removeSine()
{
    err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    for(int i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        data.sine[i] -= 0.3*sin(2 * M_PI * 440 * ((double)i/(double)SAMPLE_RATE));
    }
    isPressed = false;

}
```

When I'm pressing button, function

```
void SoundEngine::generateSine()
```

is running - it generates sound. When I release the button, method

```
void SoundEngine::removeSine()
```

removes the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with either your sound or PortAudio. The sound you're hearing at the end is just the result of the audio being abruptly stopped. Take a look at the following image of a sound that has a constant amplitude through the entire duration. This sound will have an audible pop at the end.

[image: Constant amplitude throughout the sound file]

Conversely, if we attenuate the amplitude by modifying the waveform's envelope (the same sound as in image #1) so that it resembles the sound in image #2, we won't hear any abrupt change(s) in the sound at the end.

[image]

In conclusion, if your goal is to completely eliminate the pops that you're hearing, fade out (or fade in) your sound(s).

Comment: Since it is not really playback of audio but a simple sine wave generation, instead of fading out one can simply NOT stop immediately on stop, but schedule it to stop next time the amplitude is zero.

Comment: That won't help because there's a very short time distance between a peak value and a zero (actually there are 3 zeros for every cycle), so you'll still hear a pop at the end. The solution is changing the envelope as I explained.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was, for some reason, thinking much lower than audible frequencies. Finishing a cycle in such high frequencies won't deal with the abrupt amplitude drop.

Comment: Yes, for super lower frequencies your solution would work but there wouldn't be much use :)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I'll try to somehow fade the sound. I didn't know that there is dsp.stackexchange. Thanks for this attention